# Respondi uma pergunta duplicada e minha resposta é bem parecida com a da original. Devo excluir minha resposta?

Tags: debate, respostas, perguntas-duplicadas

Me refiro a esta pergunta:

[R: Remover colunas de um dataframe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105167/r-remover-colunas-de-um-dataframe)

Respondi a pergunta e depois descobri que ela era duplicada, e minha resposta parece uma cópia das respostas da pergunta original.

Devo apagar a minha resposta?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sua resposta parece OK – e digo "parece" porque não entendo nada de R. Não achei que ela parece cópia de nenhuma das respostas à outra pergunta. Pode até dizer a mesma coisa, mas diz com suas próprias palavras e cumpre a função de responder à dúvida do AP.

Se as respostas da nova pergunta se aplicarem à pergunta original, uma opção é mesclarmos as duas. Mas peço ajuda à comunidade da tag [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) para decidir isso, porque, como eu disse, minha ignorância não permite tomar essa decisão sozinho.

Se não mesclarmos, normal também. Duplicatas geralmente são mantidas no site, devidamente marcadas, porque são pontos de entrada alternativos para encontrar a resposta (especialmente para quem chega aqui por mecanismos de busca). Portanto, não, não precisa excluir sua resposta só porque a pergunta é duplicata.