# O que está acontecendo com os votos negativos?

Tags: debate, voto-contra

Lendo [esse post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344/votos-contr%C3%A1rios-aparentemente-sem-raz%C3%A3o?rq=1) de 2013, notei que está acontecendo a mesma coisa, não sei se é impressão minha, mas desde segunda tenho notado que a quantidade de *downvotes* está aumentando bastante. Vejo perguntas boas com respostas idem, como [essa do Wallace Maxters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110162/como-remover-um-atributo-css-com-jquery) que o pessoal negativou sem critério a resposta, que me pareceu dentro do contexto.

Vi outras perguntas com a mesma situação, inclusive teve uma pergunta minha que do nada recebeu negativo também. É normal essa atitude dos usuários?

Comment: Não sei onde está o problema, mas que existe, existe. Existe também o problema dos **maria vai com as outras**. Agora como resolver é que não faço ideia.

Comment: Ontem por acaso acompanhei o caso que citei do Wallace Maxters. O cara tomou 4 downvotes em questão de segundos. Algumas perguntas novas, as vezes em 3 ou 4 minutos já tem downvotes. Percebo que a coisa anda meio sem critério nos últimos dias...

Comment: Ocorre o mesmo com positivos, mas aí ninguém reclama :)

Comment: Eu já vi bastante, tem perguntas/respostas ruins recebendo votos positivos, e perguntas e respostas ótimas sendo negativadas sem motivo e sem justificativa. Infelizmente isso vai do usuário. Muito ocorre de votarem a favor por solidariedade, e também votarem contra por não gostarem de quem postou e o voto em cascata citado pelo @JorgeB. Esse tipo de coisa não deveria existir, quem perde é o STACKOVERFLOW, e consequentemente a comunidade. Mas fazer o que, voto é a decisão do usuário, a democracia tem suas falhas também.

Comment: @Diego eu tenho visto. Será que vocè não está dando a revelia e nem perceba? Tem gente que acha que tem um critério, mas o cri´terio pode ser maluco. Claro que a pergunta é retórica e provocativa, não estou duvidando de você. Eu vivo recebendo votos positivos "estranhos". Eu vejo isto acontecer de monte. Claro que a maioria não é tão aleatório assim. É a pessoa achar bom coisa ruim. Só que ela não sabe que é ruim. Ela não conhece aquilo mas vota assim mesmo. Eu falo isto eventualmente. E tem o que o DiegoFelipe falou também, voto que não considera o conteúdo. Eu evito, mas faço também.

Comment: @bigown Quando eu disse à revelia quis dizer assim, eu leio uma pergunta, não gosto do tema do conteúdo() e voto negativo, ou leio outra e o conteúdo é sobre algum tema que eu gosto e voto positivo. Esta forma de análise deveria ser evitada não concorda? Quanto a julgar o que é ruim ou não, você tem razão, a subjetividade disso acaba tornando complicado a avaliação do conteúdo, o que eu considero ruim pra um pode ser considerado bom pra outro.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe sim, claro. Quem falou em revelia foi o outro Diego, ou as duas contas são da mesma pessoa? :) Tem coisas que só quem tem conhecimento naquilo pode dizer se é bom ou ruim, mas o pessoal vota assim mesmo. Tem muita pergunta sem pé nem cabeça, mas totalmente sem condições, não estou falando de pequenos problemas, estou falando de coisa exageradamente ruim, e tem 1, 2 às vezes 3 ou 4 votos positivos.

Comment: @bigown O AP é meu xará, é porque você marcou ele e eu acabei recebendo a notificação. Mas fui eu mesmo quem falou dos votos à revelia hehe

Comment: Eu realmente achava que faltava negativo no site, só que infelizmente o aumento de negativos não está sendo usado como eu gostaria que fosse (pra respostas erradas e ruins, quando o autor não se incomoda em melhorar, ou para perguntas com problemas sérios). Infelizmente o que eu vejo é uso por revanche ou disputas bobas. Espero que os negativos não diminuam, mas sejam usados "para o bem" (afinal, eles são a melhor coisa que o SOpt tem para evitar propagar ensinamentos errados na internet). Quanto ao positivo mal dado, esse eu reclamo faz tempo.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/revision/428736/15617/downvotes-by-user

Comment: PEDIDO DE NOVO RECURSO: obrigação de deixar um comentário explicando o voto positivo :P c/c @Bacco

Comment: @brasofilo esse aí eu já tinha falado quando diziam em obrigar pro negativo ;)

Comment: @Bacco, era só pra reforçar o meme :D Investiguei o troço mais a fundo e postei uma resposta que acho que desmascara todo esse esquema corrupto de -1 e +1 injustificado!

Comment: Em vez de obrigar a explicar o voto negativo toda santa vez (o que tornaria a caixa de comentários um monte de comentários "-1" ), eu apoiaria limitar a quantidade de votos negativos que uma pessoa pode dar no dia em relação à de positivos. Isso seria para evitar o efeito "acordei com o pé esquerdo".

Agora negativos em respostas... aí eu acho que realmente, não tem desculpa para não dar um comentário (ou pelo menos votar em um dos comentários já existentes)

Comment: Oi Diego. Tem certeza de que quer marcar a minha resposta como aceita? Eu postei o gráfico mais como subsídio para as discussões, o mais importante seriam as conclusões que podemos tirar a partir dele.

Comment: Tinha marcado a sua por ser a resposta mais séria, junto com a do Sneeps Ninja.

Comment: Em casos de debate aqui no meta, às vezes é melhor nem marcar nenhuma, assim a discussão segue "em aberto".

Comment: @brasofilo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110566/qual-o-c%c3%b3digo-para-pesquisar-dominios-dispon%c3%adveis#comment229519_110596

Comment: Como dizem, de graça até injeção na testa, downvote está apenas à um clique, não exige uma explicação, não precisa apresentar nenhum motivo. Se não vá com a cara, downvote nele, de graça.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus downvote custa ponto pra quem dá, não é de graça não. O upvote ja é free, por isso deve ser mais mal usado.

Comment: @Bacco , dessa eu não sabia, obg pelo toque!

Comment: Uma duvida, qual pergunta sua exatamente recebeu um downvote... O problema de alguns aqui é justificar os downvotes. Eu sempre deixava uma mensagem assim "pode justificar eu não vou votar negativo nas suas perguntas só porque votou na minha, só quero entender pra melhorar"... Mas ninguém nunca retornar... e pelo que noto quem costuma fazer isto são uns usuários medianamente participativos, já os com boa participação geralmente comentam sim. Tem muito usuário com menos de um ano aqui que entrou na comunidade e acha que pode aplicar as proprias regras idiotas e discorda de coisas boas...

Answer (score 19):

Fiquei curiosa pra saber se houve mesmo um aumento no número de downvotes, então decidi vasculhar os dados e descobrir.

A primeira coisa foi verificar se há mesmo um aumento no número de perguntas fechadas e removidas, desde o começo do site. Os números vêm se mantendo bem consistentes, e eu não vejo nenhum crescimento notável:

> [image: fechadas e removidas]

A seguir, olhei o número de perguntas com pontuação positiva e negativa e, novamente, não há nada fora do normal:

> [image: negativas vs positivas]

Um dos privilégios do site, quando você atinge 25.000 de reputação, é ganhar acesso à [área de estatísticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics). Lá você pode ver o histórico do número de votos, e sua distribuição. [Olhando os dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics), também não é possível ver nenhum aumento no número de votos contra.

> [image: estatísticas de votação]

Então comecei a me perguntar se talvez o número total de *votantes* no site não venha caindo, e eles não estejam votando mais contra que a favor. Usando uma [análise semelhante à que foi feita no Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299930/voting-history-statistics-request), eu olhei os dados de votação dos últimos 90 dias, agrupando os votos pela reputação dos votantes no momento do voto.

### Padrão de votação (favor vs contra) de usuários de diferentes reputações

```
Intervalo  Tipo    Rep Mediana Mediana Votos/Usuário Usuários Votos   
---------  -----   ----------- --------------------- -------- ------
< 125      Favor   62          2                     708      7610  
< 125      Contra  120         2                     73       513
125 - 500  Favor   335         4                     334      9152
125 - 500  Contra  342         2                     150      1089
500 - 3k   Favor   994         10                    268      12741
500 - 3k   Contra  1044        4                     146      1321
3k - 10k   Favor   4585        29                    55       4655
3k - 10k   Contra  4565        5                     40       823
10k - 20k  Favor   14646       195                   10       2715
10k - 20k  Contra  14342       7                     8        1498
> 20k      Favor   40441       466                   9        4410
> 20k      Contra  44717       16                    8        1688
```

### Observações

- O número de pessoas com reputação menor que 125 é quase igual ao total de votantes de reputação média (entre 125 e 3000)
- Usuários de reputação muito alta votam mais a favor que contra
- Usuários de reputação média (125-3000) são a maior parte dos votados, e votam mais a favor que contra

### Padrão de votação em perguntas fechadas rapidamente

Esta é a distribuição dos votos (a favor/contra), de usuários em diferentes níveis de reputação, em perguntas fechadas em menos de 24h e que permaneceram fechadas por mais de uma semana. Elas estão listadas por motivo de fechamento.

Votos a favor ou contra em perguntas fechadas, para cada nível de reputação:

```
Motivo                             Tipo    Votos <125  Votos 125-500  Votos 500-3k   Votos 3k-10k  Votos 10k-20k  Votos >20k
---------------------------------- ------- ----------- -------------- -------------  ------------- -------------- -----------
duplicada                          Favor   14          41             70             44            9              49
duplicada                          Contra  0           16             47             30            35             69
off-topic - padrão                 Favor   7           6              35             15            10             11
off-topic - padrão                 Contra  0           36             89             63            46             80
off-topic - não está em português  Favor   0           3              3              1             0              0
off-topic - não está em português  Contra  0           9              13             10            1              23
off-topic - não reproduzido        Favor   0           8              25             17            2              19
off-topic - não reproduzido        Contra  0           6              23             18            26             33
off-topic - outro site             Favor   0           0              0              0             0              1
off-topic - outro site             Contra  0           0              3              2             2              1
off-topic - outros                 Favor   0           4              8              0             2              2
off-topic - outros                 Contra  0           6              15             13            5              12
baseado em opinião                 Favor   4           12             23             14            3              8
baseado em opinião                 Contra  0           7              31             17            10             36
amplo demais                       Favor   7           26             37             24            3              17
amplo demais                       Contra  0           41             90             60            39             99
não está claro                     Favor   13          35             50             38            9              15
não está claro                     Contra  0           81             123            121           71             157
Total                              Favor   45          135            251            153           38             122
Total                              Contra  0           202            434            334           235            510
```

O número de usuários distintos votando nessas perguntas:

```
Motivo                             Tipo    Usuários <125  Usuários 125-500  Usuários 500-3k   Usuários 3k-10k  Usuários 10k-20k  Usuários >20k
---------------------------------- ------- -------------- ----------------- ----------------  ---------------- ----------------- --------------
duplicada                          Favor   12             20                35                15               5                 8
duplicada                          Contra  0              13                32                13               5                 4
off-topic - padrão                 Favor   7              5                 27                10               3                 8
off-topic - padrão                 Contra  0              26                52                14               5                 4
off-topic - não está em português  Favor   0              3                 3                 1                0                 0
off-topic - não está em português  Contra  0              5                 13                4                1                 3
off-topic - não reproduzido        Favor   0              3                 18                10               2                 6
off-topic - não reproduzido        Contra  0              5                 19                10               3                 3
off-topic - outro site             Favor   0              0                 0                 0                0                 1
off-topic - outro site             Contra  0              0                 3                 2                2                 1
off-topic - outros                 Favor   0              3                 7                 0                2                 2
off-topic - outros                 Contra  0              5                 14                7                2                 4
baseado em opinião                 Favor   4              11                17                9                3                 6
baseado em opinião                 Contra  0              7                 20                5                4                 3
amplo demais                       Favor   7              11                21                11               2                 8
amplo demais                       Contra  0              22                45                10               4                 3
não está claro                     Favor   13             11                29                12               4                 7
não está claro                     Contra  0              43                52                14               5                 3
Total                              Favor   35             37                76                29               9                 8
Total                              Contra  0              74                102               27               7                 6
```

### Quem remove os posts?

Também olhei as estatísticas sobre os posts removidos no último ano, e quem os removeu. Foram **8653 posts removidos**, distribuídos da seguinte maneira:

```
Tipo Post Removido por...                                      Nr Remoções  % do total 
--------- ---------------------------------------------------- ------------ ---------- 
Question  Voto do autor                                        1886         21.80 %    
Question  Auto-remoção: AbandonadoFechado                      1856         21.45 %    
Answer    Voto do autor                                        1524         17.61 %    
Answer    Convertido em comentário                             807          9.33 %     
Answer    Moderador                                            713          8.24 %     
Answer    Análise                                              484          5.59 %     
Question  Auto-remoçào: PerguntasMortas                        414          4.78 %     
Answer    Pergunta removida (Auto-remoção: AbandonadoFechado)  322          3.72 %     
Question  Auto-remoção: PerguntasAbandonadas                   220          2.54 %     
Answer    Pergunta removida (Voto do autor)                    145          1.68 %     
Answer    Votos de outros                                      118          1.36 %     
Question  Moderador                                            68           0.79 %     
Answer    Sinalização spam/ofensiva                            19           0.22 %     
Answer    Pergunta removida (Moderador)                        18           0.21 %     
Answer    Autor removido                                       18           0.21 %     
Question  Autor removido                                       11           0.13 %     
Question  Votos de outros                                      8            0.09 %     
Question  Auto-remoção: Migração                               8            0.09 %     
Question  Sinalização spam/ofensiva                            7            0.08 %     
Answer    Pergunta removida (Autor removido)                   4            0.05 %     
Answer    Pergunta migrada                                     1            0.01 %     
Answer    Pergunta removida (Votos de outros)                  1            0.01 %     
Answer    Votação                                              1            0.01 %
```

### Observações sobre a metodologia

- Os votos contados em usuários com menos de 125 de reputação são por conta de invalidações de votos, remoções de usuários ou por conta de alguma outra esquisitice. Nós tentamos estimar a reputação na hora do voto da melhor maneira possível, mas conseguir dados perfeitos seria incrivelmente difícil e custoso. Então, ao invés de ignorar esses números, resolvi deixá-los, para dar uma ideia geral da precisão dos dados.
- Como o voto é contado junto com a reputação, é possível que algum usuário acabe em mais de um grupo, nesse intervalo de 90 dias. Se um usuário tinha menos que 125 pontos no início da contagem, mas ultrapassou esse valor durante esse tempo, seus votos iniciais vão aparecer no primeiro grupo, e os votos seguintes no próximo grupo.

### Os votos estão sendo dados nos novatos?

Se todo mundo vem votando normalmente, a favor e contra, ainda resta saber **se os votos estão sendo dados nos usuários novatos no site**.

Bom, não. Não há nenhum aumento também no número de votos contra em posts de novos usuários.

> [image: Novatos]

Isso significa que, se há um aumento no número de downvotes, não é por conta dos posts de quem chegou no site agora. Ou seja, os votos contra são uma consequência normal de um site em crescimento.

Um site maior vai ter mais votos! É exatamente o que uma comunidade precisa para continuar crescendo.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the chart I posted, will delete.

Answer (score 8):

Olhe para a pergunta e passe o mouse na seta down e reflita nesses perguntas:

---

**essa pergunta é útil?** - Mesmo que não seja útil para você, você acredita que ela será usada por outro usuário?

Lembre-se que o que não tem utilidade para você pode ser útil para alguém antes de votar com esse pensamento

---

**essa pergunta é clara?** - Essa pergunta esta escrita de maneira que alguém que conhece do assunto posso identificar claramente o problema enfrentado?

Caso a pergunta esteja faltando informações que são necessárias para reduzir a abrangência chegando a um ponto bem especifico e definido, talvez a pergunta precise ser editada.

---

**essa pergunta mostra um esforço de pesquisa?**

Aqui partimos de uma subjetividade, onde é normal haver algumas discordâncias, quanto mais pessoas visualizarem e votarem melhor, pois se a maioria votou em down é "sinal" que realmente pode ter faltado algum esforço de pesquisa, mas se a maioria dos votos foi up então esta certo, talvez essa pergunta [Wallace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110162/como-remover-um-atributo-css-com-jquery) seja um insulto aos olhos do rapaz que escreveu o código e publicou no site, para ele talvez o Sr. Wallace não se esforçou, mas para a maioria dos usuários aqui do site, não foi assim tão fácil achar o material necessário.

Comment: Esse "esforço de pesquisa" quer dizer google ou pesquisa dentro da comunidade? Se for, eu posso pesquisar em inglês (apesar de ter preguiça de ler, eu entendo). Mas talvez minha pergunta ajude outros usuários, que, pesquisando em português no google, ache o tal conteúdo.

Comment: Acho que essa história do esforço de pesquisa se resume a 1 - Verificar se já existe no site; 2 - Se não existe e se é proveitosa para o site (caso da do Wallace). Depois temos o ponto 3 que é todas as outras que não existem no site mas que não são de caras proveitosas para o futuro, ai o utilizador tem de mostrar o que já fez, o que já tentou para que o possamos ajudar, e depois quiça a pergunta fique proveitosa para o futuro.

Comment: Enfim @JorgeB., cada um usa a desculpa que quiser pra negativar, rsrsrsrs.

Comment: Na verdade historicamente o esforço de pesquisa é ter tentado fazer alguma coisa. Isto funciona mais para casos concretos. Para casos mais conceituais o esforço é ter procurado antes, é demonstrar porque está perguntando aqui. Eventualmente ser transparente quando sabe a resposta e está postando para ter o conteúdo pode ser interessante para pelo menos todos saberem do que se trata. Eu tenho a impressão que o negativo pode até vir porque a pessoa acha que está havendo má fé, a pessoa está dando uma de [joão-sem-braço](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/jo%E3o+sem+bra%E7o/).

Comment: Pensa no *spam*. Tem documentação na rede mostrando como a pessoa deve proceder qdo postar alguma coisa que ela é parte interessada. Ser transparente é chave para não ser considerado *spam*. Muitas vezes saber fazer o texto direitinho pode ser a diferença entre tomar o negativo ou não. Ainda que possa ser injusto, muitas vezes ele pode ser evitado. O que não dá para evitar é o negativo de perseguição. Mas nem todos negativos que tomamos são de perseguição.

Answer (score 6):

> ## O que está acontecendo com os votos negativos?

Me disseram que houve votos para que os negativos chegassem mais rápido, mas parece que o busão tava demorando...
Perguntei insistentemente sobre o assunto à equipe do Stack Exchange, mas não quiseram afirmar ou negar nada.

Segue prova visual dos fatos:

[image: copyright indeterminado, não encontrei a origem da foto]

<sup><sub>PS: pesquisei de todo jeito a origem da foto acima, mas só encontrei versões com aquele `© A...` cortado :(</sub></sup>

Comment: Ta vendo esse votos positivos nessa resposta mostra que o sentimento fala mais alto que uma regra, essa resposta nunca deveria receber votos positivos, pois ela não responde a pergunta, não é útil, mas, é engraçada então votaram com o sentimento e não com a razão, esse é o problema.

Comment: @Ninja, "problema"? Como assim, não responde pergunta? Sigo a tradição centenária de avacalhar com o sistema de maneira séria. "Sentimento"? Se refere ao "tudo azul", "tudo é positivo", " votar negativo é feio"?  Meh...

Comment: No site principal, seriedade é a regra; aqui, nem vem que não tem, espaço de livre pensamento.

Comment: @brasofilo o problema é que o pessoal vota assim no principal também. E tem alguns exemplos de respostas bem votadas e que não só coisas legais, não úteis. E defendido pela SE. Aí fica difícil cobrar comportamento adequado das pessoas.

Answer (score 6):

Olhando todas respostas aqui dá pra ter uma noção do que pode estar acontecendo, o Diego perguntou acho que no intuito de a *"comunidade formou algum critério do que negativar"* e nem todos nós sabemos qual é, pois começaram a supostamente surgir estranhos votos negativos.

Mas ao olhar as respostas aqui:

- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4806/3635 Uma critica ou possíveis causas do downvote
- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4852/3635 Uma analise detalhada do andamento
- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4870/3635 Uma reclamação de usuários negativando os novatos

Quero dizer, acho que o Diego quer saber uma coisa, mas cada pessoa entendeu coisas diferentes... longe de mim criticar, não é isso, **POR FAVOR NÃO ME ENTENDAM MAL**, o que eu quero dizer é que isso mostra o que possivelmente esta causando essa sensação de votos negativos aleatórios, cada pessoa que veem aqui até a comunidade parece que tem uma ideia do certo e errado e do que é melhor para comunidade.

> O texto a seguir é longo, se tem preguiça de ler vá até o final e procure a palavra **Resumindo** e **Resumindo 2** usando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Veja um exemplo, uma vez peguei um usuário que estava editando várias perguntas adicionando tags, a pergunta era sobre [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) mas a resposta que resolveu o problema foi [apache](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) então ele adicionou a tag [htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htaccess) eu fui falar pra ele que aquele tipo de pergunta poderia ter vários tipos de solução e que a tag não fazia sentido, ele "bateu o pé" falando que as perguntas tinham que evoluir também, quero dizer ele pensou que aqui não era uma Q&A, acho que ele imaginava que aqui fosse um "wikipédia da vida".

Sei que esta confuso o que eu disse, mas vou chegar lá logo... O que quero dizer é que os novos usuário começam a participar aqui e começam eles a criarem ideias do que é certo e errado e começam a aplicar as próprias regras sem nenhuma consideração pelo que já foi feito e ainda acreditam estar fazendo o BEM.

É o seguinte o site tem um [MODELO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange), tanto de perguntas e respostas como condutas, o site tem um META o qual várias coisas são discutidas e definidas, até situações de comportamentos como **por exemplo**:

- [Que tratamento dar a esta pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4846/3635)
- [Como lidar com a pressão dos "colegas"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4798/3635)
- [O que é uma pergunta ampla?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4801/3635)
- [Eu posso utilizar o conteúdo das perguntas e respostas do SOpt para fazer trabalhos de faculdade?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4777/3635)
- [A dificuldade singular de julgar uma questão dentro de contexto ou fora de contexto no SOPT](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4749/3635)
- [respondi uma pergunta duplicada e minha resposta é bem parecida com a da original. Devo excluir minha resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4706/3635)
- [Licença MIT – Como utilizar códigos do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4685/3635)

São alguns exemplos, são questões no META que nos ajudam a saber como nos comportar no site principal, elas nos instruem, mas eu pergunto pra vocês, alguém lê? Provavelmente vão dizer "SIM", mas a verdade é que poucos lêem.

Contando o numero de visitas por pergunta e upvotes/downvotes nestas postagens no meta e o numero de participantes venho a presumir que alguns apenas passam por lá e outros nem sabem que o META existe, quem lê faz bom proveito e digo a estes que usam bem o META:

> **PARABÉNS, VOCÊ SABE PARTICIPAR**
>
> [image: é isso ae]

Agora vou chegar "ao finalmentes"... O problema é todo esse, tem "muito zé" que chega aqui querendo aloprar, se achando dono da verdade e querendo aplicar as proprias regras, sai dando downvote ou upvotes (é tem muito upvote equivocado, geralmente por caridade) sem pensar sem entender a comunidade, sem participar de verdade.

Um exemplo de comportamento que eu discuti e pessoalmente acho que a minha opinião reflete bem a opinião da comunidade é nesta pergunta:

- [Votos para fechar perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2673/3635)

Vejam houve bastante discussão lá nos comentários e acho que tanto a resposta do @JorgeB. quanto a minha definem bem o porque é bom fechar uma pergunta com problemas, no entanto outro dia no chat um usuário com 3k (pontos o suficiente pra ser considerado bem participativo) veio reclamar de suposto fechamento indevido (de minha parte) em algumas perguntas, eu expliquei pra ele e mandei o link https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635, ele disse: *eu não vou ler isso* e ficou reclamando que eu fechava rápido demais as perguntas, eu devo ter tentando explicar umas 8 vezes que tudo que é fechado pode ser reaberto e que aquilo é apenas para evitar respostas que podem ser equivocadas para a pergunta, mas ele foi teimoso e por fim não leu nada que eu mandei sobre o META.

### Resumindo

O site tem um [modelo pré-definido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange), a comunidade forma um "modelo" (ou regras) em volta desse [pré-definido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange), as pessoas chegam aqui e levam muitas coisas para o lado pessoal e até acham que isso se trata de uma espécie de fórum, não leem o Help e muito menos o META, pois acham que o no máximo o META para resolver problemas de momento, como reabrir perguntas.

Mas o que as pessoas precisam entender é que aqui discutimos muito mais coisas inclusive comportamento.

Então os downvotes e upvotes estranhos só surgem porque muitos querem aplicar as proprias regras.

### Situações de downvotes equivocados

Eu certa vez fiz duas perguntas e eu mesmo respondi, tomei alguns downvotes em ambas, mas Help é bem claro sobre auto-respoder suas perguntas:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

E o proprio blog do *stack overflow* explica

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

  > Jeff [escreveu](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/):
  >
  > - if you have a question that you already know the answer to
  > - if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
  > - it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.

Mas as pessoas que votaram negativo nunca leram isso e provavelmente pensaram que eu fui oportunista.

### Situações de upvotes equivocados

A situação é a seguinte, vou dar alguns exemplos:

- Certa vez postei uma resposta que era para ser de outra pergunta e ganhei dois upvotes, mas se ler a resposta, nada tinha haver com a pergunta (eu deletei ela ao perceber o problema) ou seja falta de atenção.
- Também houve a situação que o usuário perguntou sobre como evitar o cache em página geradas por php, o usuário postou uma resposta de como bloquear o cache do google-chrome nas configurações do browser e ganhou 1 voto positivo, só que bloquear o cache de um navegador não vai resolver pra todos usuários que acessam o site que o AP estava desenvolvendo e obviamente não era uma resposta nem sobre php e nem sobre servidor, mas mesmo assim ganhou um +1.
- Tem as situações (que são as mais comuns), geralmente a pergunta esta muito confusa, ou nem tem código conforme o https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve pede e geralmente porque outro usuário achou legal ou "achou útil" ele dá +1 (e muitas vezes é por caridade, eu vejo que quando uma pergunta toma alguns negativos, sempre tem um pra dar +1 pois acha injusto).

> [@bigown disse](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4800/o-que-est%C3%A1-acontecendo-com-os-votos-negativos#comment15800_4800):
>
> *Ocorre o mesmo com positivos, mas aí ninguém reclama :)*

### Upvotes/Downvotes e comportamento

Eu não estou dizendo que devemos ditar regras de como você deve votar, mas esta bem claro que tem gente que gosta de aplicar as próprias regras e acaba causando sérias dores de cabeça a outras pessoas, eles pensam que dar upvote por dó vai ajudar, sendo que só ensina o outro usuário a ser *preguiçoso*.

Tem uma coisa muito bem escrita no [help/editing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) que inclusive fica dentro da categoria [**Nosso modelo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange) (aquilo que eu to falando desde o começo), tem gente que não gosta que editem suas postagens, mas o próprio Help diz:

> Editar é importante para manter as perguntas e respostas claras, relevantes e atualizadas. Se não se sente confortável com a ideia de que suas contribuições sejam editadas de modo colaborativo por outros usuários confiáveis, este site não é para você.

Ou seja, é um tipo de comportamento esperado da comunidade, mas geralmente (e principalmente) quem chega aqui e pega o bonde andando não gosta e isso ocorre com tudo, downvotes, upvotes, fechamentos, comentários. Existem ações já esperadas, mas tem muita gente que chega aqui discorda e fica fazendo o contrário pra aporrinhar ou pra tentar forçar o modelo que eles tem na cabeça.

### Resumindo 2

E para o meu ver é todo esse o problema:

- Poucos querem seguir o [*modelo*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)
- Poucos querem ler o Help
- Poucos participam do META
- Pouquíssimos leem as postagens mais antigas do META
- Muitos querem inventar regras e discordar de quem já tem um tempo de casa
- Não é um problema recente, é que aumentou o numero de usuários e por suas vez aumentou o numero de usuários que não seguem "o modelo".