# Que tratamento dar a esta pergunta?

Tags: suporte

O título desta pergunta: [Como usar mais de uma extends?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111601/2541) expressa, de facto, a dificuldade encontrada pelo AP.
No entanto, ela surge na sequência da tentativa de implementar o código fornecido na resposta a esta pergunta: [Zoom com dedos em app](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74540/2541).

Pelo título, ela eventualmente poderá ser considerada duplicata desta: [Java não possui herança múltipla?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22718/2541). A própria resposta que recebeu aponta nesse sentido.
Por outro lado, analisando o conteúdo e os comentários, o que é pretendido é como implementar o código da resposta à outra pergunta. Algo que pouco interesse poderá ter para outros.

Acho que a pergunta deve ser fechada, mas não sei qual o motivo que devo indicar.

Duplicata? Pelo título e resposta.
Não está clara? Por ser difícil responder sem conhecer a ligação à resposta à outra pergunta.
Fora de escopo? Por não ter interesse para mais ninguém.

Ou sou eu que estou a complicar, porque o que interessa é fechá-la?

Comment: ramaral ou as perguntas estão fora do sitio ou os links, como não sei qual é podes rever isso?

Comment: @JorgeB. Corrigido, obrigado.

Comment: Como eu não tenho plena convicção eu preferi deixar para outras pessoas decidirem, dei o subsídio para as pessoas analisarem se é duplicada, o que acho que é. Talvez a pergunta não esteja clara. Agora tem uma resposta que seria invalidada se a pergunta for modificada ou seja dado outra interpretação para ela. Ser específico não sei se é problemas porque eu acho que uns 80% do que é perguntado é específico. O quanto isto é suficiente para considerarmos que para fechar eu não sei, acho que não precisamos ser rígidos quanto a isto. Eu acho que esta não salva +. Ele pode fazer outra + específica.

Comment: Eu acho que o mais importante é fechá-la. Mas claramente o motivo fora de escopo sobrepõe-se aos outros. Como pode ser duplicata se está fora do escopo? Mas, por outro lado, ela pode não estar clara e levar a estar fora do escopo e/ou duplicata.

Comment: @bigown Como você, também tive dúvidas. Consegue me dizer a razão das suas? São as mesmas ou foram outras?

Comment: @ramaral Não tenho tantas dúvidas, só não quis martelar a duplicata (eu tenho ouro em Java), preferi deixar para outras pessoas decidirem. Eu não acho ela tão claramente duplicata, pode haver discordância. Além disto a resposta na original é minha, poderiam achar que fiz por benefício pessoal. E tem muita gente que adora fazer acusações contra mim. O fato dos comentários indicarem algo um pouco diferente, ajuda não fechar por este motivo, mas aí não sei como poderia ser respondida. Eu prefiro considerar o estado original que indica ser duplicata.Até agora ninguém conseguiu dar uma boa resposta

Comment: Você domina o assunto muito mais que eu, é mais fácil você decidir que eu :P

Comment: @bigown Compreendo a questão do "ouro", não concordo é que se sinta condicionado por "....... a resposta na original é minha, ......." e "... tem muita gente que adora fazer acusações contra mim."  Com "Até agora ninguém conseguiu dar uma boa resposta" você está a referir-se à minha pergunta ou à outra?

Comment: À pergunta foco do debate. Ela teve bastante atenção e ninguém deu uma resposta razoável, a existente só diz o que já foi dito na outra. Se eu estivesse 100% convicto eu até fecharia no martelo, mas a é possível argumentar que ele quer algo mais específico do que foi respondido. Claro que este argumento acaba sendo válido para quase tudo.